# How can I name Classes using Snake Casing?

Tags: naming-conventions, camelcasing, pascalcasing, snakecasing

While coding in Java, I prefer to use pascal case for my class names and camel case for objects.

For example:

`TextView textView1, textView2;`

But in C++, I prefer to use snake casing to name my variables. How can I do this for class names and object names?

I’ve thought of using _t for the class names like I’ve seen used for some data types.

example:

`text_view_t text_view1, text_view2;`

Is this acceptable? Is there any other way to name classes while using only snake casing?

Edit: My goal here is to use only snake casing in my code because it makes C++ code look neater, in my opinion.

Comment: Why not just capitalize the first letter, e.g *Text_view*?